# Unity Editor freezing while running timers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, recursion, minimax

I'm taking a coursera course where an assignment I'm working on involves completing work on a "take the last rock" style puzzle. For this assignment, the puzzle needs to run with two AI players 600 times at varying levels of AI difficulty. The problem is that after implementing my changes (which involve recursive Minimax algorithms) I'm running into an issue where the unity editor seems to freeze after a few games. It always seems to happen while the newgamedelaytimer is running (timer code provided by the instructor). I've watched it run in debug mode and after a few games the timer stops incrementing and I have to restart Unity.
Here is the code for the base game (where the newgamedelaytimer is called) and the course provided timer.

Is there something I'm missing here?

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

/// <summary>
/// Game manager
/// </summary>
public class DontTakeTheLastTeddy : MonoBehaviour, ITakeTurnInvoker, IGameOverInvoker,
    IGameStartingInvoker
{
    Board board;
    Player player1;
    Player player2;

    // multiple games support
    Timer newGameDelayTimer;
    PlayerName firstMovePlayer = PlayerName.Player1;
    const int TotalGames = 600;
    int gamesPlayed = 0;
    
    // events invoked by class
    TakeTurn takeTurnEvent = new TakeTurn();
    GameOver gameOverEvent = new GameOver();
    GameStarting gameStartingEvent = new GameStarting();
    
    #region Constructor

    // Uncomment the code below after copying this class into the console
    // app for the automated grader. DON'T uncomment it now; it won't
    // compile in a Unity project

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// 
    /// Note: The class in the Unity solution doesn't use a constructor;
    /// this constructor is to support automated grading
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameObject">the game object the script is attached to</param>
    //public DontTakeTheLastTeddy(GameObject gameObject) :
    //    base(gameObject)
    //{
    //}

    #endregion
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Awake is called before Start
    /// 
    /// Leave this method public to support automated grading
    /// </summary>
    public void Awake()
    {
        // retrieve board and player references
        board = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Board").GetComponent<Board>();
        player1 = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player1").GetComponent<Player>();
        player2 = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player2").GetComponent<Player>();

        // register as invoker and listener
        EventManager.AddTakeTurnInvoker(this);
        EventManager.AddGameOverInvoker(this);
        EventManager.AddGameStartingInvoker(this);
        EventManager.AddTurnOverListener(HandleTurnOverEvent);
        EventManager.AddGameOverListener(HandleGameOverEvent);
        
        // set up timer for delay between games
        newGameDelayTimer = gameObject.AddComponent<Timer>();
        newGameDelayTimer.Duration = 1.5f;
        newGameDelayTimer.AddTimerFinishedListener(HandleTimerFinishedEvent);

        // initialize statistics class
        Statistics.Initialize();
    }

    private void HandleGameOverEvent(PlayerName arg0, Difficulty arg1, Difficulty arg2)
    {
        Debug.Log("Starting New Game Delay timer");
        newGameDelayTimer.Run();
        //HandleTimerFinishedEvent();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Use this for initialization
    /// </summary>
    void Start()
    {
        StartGame(PlayerName.Player1, Difficulty.Easy, Difficulty.Easy);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the given listener for the TakeTurn event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="listener">listener</param>
    public void AddTakeTurnListener(UnityAction<PlayerName, Configuration> listener)
    {
        takeTurnEvent.AddListener(listener);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the given listener for the GameOver event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="listener">listener</param>
    public void AddGameOverListener(
        UnityAction<PlayerName, Difficulty, Difficulty> listener)
    {
        gameOverEvent.AddListener(listener);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the given listener for the GameStarting event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="listener">listener</param>
    public void AddGameStartingListener(UnityAction listener)
    {
        gameStartingEvent.AddListener(listener);
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Starts a game with the given player taking the
    /// first turn
    /// 
    /// Leave this method public to support automated grading
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="firstPlayer">player taking first turn</param>
    /// <param name="player1Difficulty">difficulty for player 1</param>
    /// <param name="player2Difficulty">difficulty for player 2</param>
    public void StartGame(PlayerName firstPlayer, Difficulty player1Difficulty,
        Difficulty player2Difficulty)
    {
        // set player difficulties
        player1.Difficulty = player1Difficulty;
        player2.Difficulty = player2Difficulty;

        // create new board
        board.CreateNewBoard();
        takeTurnEvent.Invoke(firstPlayer,
            board.Configuration);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the TurnOver event by having the 
    /// other player take their turn
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="player">who finished their turn</param>
    /// <param name="newConfiguration">the new board configuration</param>
    void HandleTurnOverEvent(PlayerName player, 
        Configuration newConfiguration)
    {
        board.Configuration = newConfiguration;

        // check for game over
        if (newConfiguration.Empty)
        {
            // fire event with winner
            if (player == PlayerName.Player1)
            {
                gameOverEvent.Invoke(PlayerName.Player2, player1.Difficulty, player2.Difficulty);
            }
            else
            {
                gameOverEvent.Invoke(PlayerName.Player1, player1.Difficulty, player2.Difficulty);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // game not over, so give other player a turn
            if (player == PlayerName.Player1)
            {
                takeTurnEvent.Invoke(PlayerName.Player2,
                    newConfiguration);
            }
            else
            {
                takeTurnEvent.Invoke(PlayerName.Player1,
                    newConfiguration);
            }
        }
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Starts a new game when the new game delay timer finishes
    /// </summary>
    void HandleTimerFinishedEvent()
    {
        Debug.Log("Finished new Game Timer");
        // constant provided for autograder support
        if (!GameConstants.PlaySingleGame)
        {
            if (gamesPlayed < TotalGames)
            {
                if (gamesPlayed % 100 == 0)
                {
                    // uncomment the line below and implement a
                    // SetPlayerDifficulties method
                    SetPlayerDifficulties(gamesPlayed);
                }

                gamesPlayed++;
                //Debug.Log("Games Played: " + gamesPlayed);
                // alternate player making first move in game
                if (firstMovePlayer == PlayerName.Player1)
                {
                    firstMovePlayer = PlayerName.Player2;
                }
                else
                {
                    firstMovePlayer = PlayerName.Player1;
                }
                
                StartGame(firstMovePlayer, player1.Difficulty, player2.Difficulty);
            }
            else
            {
                // move to statistics scene when all games have been played
                SceneManager.LoadScene("statistics");
            }
        }
    }

    private void SetPlayerDifficulties(int gamesPlayed)
    {
        if (gamesPlayed == 100)
        {
            player1.Difficulty = Difficulty.Medium;
            player2.Difficulty = Difficulty.Medium;
        }
        else if (gamesPlayed == 200)
        {
            player1.Difficulty = Difficulty.Hard;
            player2.Difficulty = Difficulty.Hard;
        }
        else if (gamesPlayed == 300)
        {
            player1.Difficulty = Difficulty.Easy;
            player2.Difficulty = Difficulty.Medium;
        }
        else if (gamesPlayed == 400)
        {
            player2.Difficulty = Difficulty.Hard;
        }
        else if (gamesPlayed == 500)
        {
            player1.Difficulty = Difficulty.Medium;
            player2.Difficulty = Difficulty.Hard;
        }
    }
}
```

Timer.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

/// <summary>
/// A timer
/// </summary>
public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region Fields

    // timer duration
    float totalSeconds = 0;

    // timer execution
    float elapsedSeconds = 0;
    bool running = false;

    // support for TimerFinished event
    bool started = false;
    TimerFinished timerFinished = new TimerFinished();

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the duration of the timer
    /// The duration can only be set if the timer isn't currently running
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>duration</value>
    public float Duration
    {
        set
        {
            if (!running)
            {
                totalSeconds = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets whether or not the timer has finished running
    /// This property returns false if the timer has never been started
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>true if finished; otherwise, false.</value>
    public bool Finished
    {
        get { return started && !running; } 
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets whether or not the timer is currently running
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>true if running; otherwise, false.</value>
    public bool Running
    {
        get { return running; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets ho wmany seconds are left on the timer
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>seconds left</value>
    public float SecondsLeft
    {
        get 
        {
            if (running)
            {
                return totalSeconds - elapsedSeconds; 
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Update is called once per frame
    /// </summary>
    void Update()
    {   
        // update timer and check for finished
        if (running)
        {
            elapsedSeconds += Time.fixedDeltaTime;
            if (elapsedSeconds >= totalSeconds)
            {
                running = false;
                timerFinished.Invoke();
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Runs the timer
    /// Because a timer of 0 duration doesn't really make sense,
    /// the timer only runs if the total seconds is larger than 0
    /// This also makes sure the consumer of the class has actually 
    /// set the duration to something higher than 0
    /// </summary>
    public void Run()
    {   
        // only run with valid duration
        if (totalSeconds > 0)
        {
            started = true;
            running = true;
            elapsedSeconds = 0;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops the timer
    /// </summary>
    public void Stop()
    {
        started = false;
        running = false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the given number of seconds to the timer
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="seconds">time to add</param>
    public void AddTime(float seconds)
    {
        totalSeconds += seconds;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the given listener for the TimerFinished event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="listener">listener</param>
    public void AddTimerFinishedListener(UnityAction listener)
    {
        timerFinished.AddListener(listener);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: I would narrow down your code to be a replicable smaller sample. If you believe it to be the timer, then the rest of the game code is not necessarily needed for the question. If Unity freezes, there is most likely an infinite loop somewhere. I would look at the function `HandleTimerFinishedEvent` as it is called by `Invoke` as a listener for when the `timer` is complete. If you are seeing the timer drop to 0 in the inspector and the timer is still running, it could be continually calling this function resulting in some form of crash.